# Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html on individual site

Tags: javascript, php, html, linux, webserver

plucking a last ditch attempt to see if anyone else can shed some light on this issue. Im serving some ads across a network of sites I own. now these ads work perfectly on all sites but 1.

the issue is on this one sight the ad unit is failing to serve and displaying this error in chrome console.

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://ib.adnxs.com/ttj?id=2148034&size=468x60". t?id=e5ff188c-e6f2-4e92-a5a0-0af846078ff6&size=468x60:1
(anonymous function)

but on other sites using exactly same source and on same server they are serving fine.

here is a link to the site where the ad is not loading properly:
http://www.justproxy.co.uk/index.php?q=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5pdHYuY29tLw%3D%3D

any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

When I load your site I get a javascript error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'focus' of null"  This occurs because the `onload` method attempts to focus on an element with id `address_box`.  There doesn't seem to be such an element on the page.  This breaks all of the scripts.

Comment: whoops so yeah thats some old script left behind but shouldnt cause any issues ive removed it either way. so link ive given you has expired. if you are to open http://www.justproxy.co.uk and type in a URL itv.com in the input and hit enter then you will notce some ads load at the top of the page there should be 3 ads but when there are 2 that means you are seeing the failed load im talking about if you check console you will see the error ive stated above.

Comment: @user3245801 ok, but now I'm not even seeing the script you reference in your question being loaded.